# React native TouchableOpacity onPress not working for UselessTextInput

Tags: javascript, react-native, touchableopacity

```
<TouchableOpacity 
    style={{backgroundColor: '#FF00FF'}}
    onPress={this.inputField}
>

    <UselessTextInput
        multiline = {true}
        numberOfLines = {4}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
    />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

The function onPress call is:

```
inputField() {
    console.log('Clicked')
}
```

i can't find any solution y its not working
i tried changing `onPress` to `onPress={() => { console.log('Clicked') }}`
 it still didn't work

Can anyone tell me y its not working what i m doing wrong in it

Comment: Why you use TouchableOpacity out of the TextInput ?

Comment: If you want to handle first click of TextInput, you can use onFocus property of TextInput. "onFocus={this.inputField}"

Comment: Happens to me as well on IOS simulator (Android ok)

Answer (score 0):

try passing an arrowed function to the onClick prop, otherwise it won't be executed when you click on it, there are two different ways which lead to the same result :

first (in the function declaration) :

```
inputField = () => {
  console.log('Clicked')
}
```

second (in the onPress prop) :

```
onPress={() => this.inputField}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `()` to the `this.inputField`, like the code:

```
onPress={()=>{this.inputField()}}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to a question, should be a comment. Please see [When should I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).